# How to print the thumbnail only if a post has a thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am using the following code to print another image that is in my images folder in casa a post has no thumbnail but it is giving me errors on the else statement saying that there is a syntax error:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
       echo '<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <figure><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></figure></a>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<figure><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/images/stone.jpg" /></figure></a>';
    }
?>
```

However, if I paste this code:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      echo '<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <figure><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></figure></a>';
   }
   else{
   }
?>
```

It gives no error but also it does not display the thumbnail

Hope you can help

Comment: what are the errors? plz mention

Comment: What error do you get ..please let us know,so we can help you

Comment: @Arsalan Mithani. Please check my edited question. It shows nothing now that I removed the else statement code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside else condition where no image assigned.

```
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    ?><a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
    </a><?php
} else {
    echo '<figure><a href="add_link_here"><img src="'.get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory").'/images/stone.jpg" /></figure></a>';
}
```

Comment: I actually found the answer. Mind making it better by showing how can I wrap the thumbnail in a permalink?

Comment: Do you need to add permalink in image?

Comment: Yes. Need the thumbnail to be wrapped in a permalink

Comment: See my updated answer.Do you need permalink in if condition or only else condition?Because added it only for else condition here.

Comment: Not really that. Looking at my answer, the function the_post_thumbnail(); should be wrapped in an a tag using the permalink.

Comment: JUst updated answer ,hope this helped you.

Comment: Problem solved. Appreciate the support

Answer (score 0):

I found a snippet from codex and it actually works.

```
<?php
    // Must be inside a loop.

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
    else {
        echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) 
            . '/images/stone.jpg" />';
    }
?>
```